Graph in octave based on algorythm
I have such a chart,

and I need to replicate it in Octave; it pertains to an algorithm below:
Data: f, xa, xb, n
Results: I
function f_rectI(f, xa, xb, n)
h ← (xb − ax)/n
i ← 1, 2, ..., n
X ← xa + (i − 1/2) * h
Y ← f(X)
I ← h * sum(Y)

and I came out with this code
function f_rectI_plot(f, xa, xb, n)
% Calculate function values at xi points
h = (xb - xa) / n;
X = xa + (0.5:h:(n-0.5)*h);
Y = f(X);

% Orange color in RGB format
orange_rgb = [217,83,25] / 255;
blue_rgb = [16,123,193] / 255;

% Bar plot
figure;
bar(X, Y, h, 'FaceColor', blue_rgb,'EdgeColor', blue_rgb); % Bars in blue color
hold on;

% Connected centers of bars with function values
plot(X, Y, '-', 'Color', orange_rgb, 'LineWidth', 2); % Line in orange color

% Set axis ranges
xlim([-2, 2]); % Range for x axis
ylim([0, 12]); % Range for y axis

% Set axis scaling only on the bottom and left sides
set(gca, 'Box', 'off', 'TickDir', 'out', 'XAxisLocation', 'bottom', 'YAxisLocation', 'left');

% Calculate integral value
I = sum(Y) * h;

% Add information about the integral
fprintf('Approximate integral value: %.10f\n', I);
end

% Sample data
xa = -2; % Range for x axis
xb = 2;  % Range for x axis
n = 10; % number of partitions
f = @(x) x.^2 + 1; % Sample function

% Call the function to plot the graph
f_rectI_plot(f, xa, xb, n);

I'm having trouble replicating this chart since the columns aren't aligned, and they aren't transparent inside.

you're setting both the the facecolor and edgecolor to blue_rgb. you can set 'facecolor' to 'none'

you need to control / set the properties of the bar graph to get the bar graph to look the way you want. when you create a bar object you can see the available properties from:
h = bar ([1,2,3);
get (h);

In particular, your current code is setting both facecolor and edgecolor to blue_rgb.  (You even have a comment saying "bars in blue color", and that is what you get.)  bars are 'patch' objects, so you can set it to similar options as 'facecolor' for patches. see https://docs.octave.org/latest/Patch-Properties.html .   In particular I would set this to "none" to get transparent bars.
Next, you want wider bars.  The 'barwidth property is a bar-specific property.  a barwidth of 1 typically creates bars with no spacing.
So, just changing your bar command to:
bar(X, Y, h, 'FaceColor', 'none' ,'EdgeColor', blue_rgb, 'barwidth", 1);
should get you closer to what you want.
(Note that your function is not currently creating the same bar heights as the figure shown. I assume since you have it marked as a 'sample function' that you can adjust that as necessary.)
